# Bash-style Programming-quote functionality in Matlab?

Tags: bash, matlab

I would use programming-quote like this in Bash

```
$ export b=`ls /`
$ echo $b
Applications Library Network System Users Volumes tmp usr var
```

and now I want to find similar functionality in Matlab. Also, I want to find a command that outputs relative paths, not absolute paths like Matlab's `ls` -- I feel like reinventing the wheel if I am parsing this with a regex. I need to find this command to debug what is wrong with namespaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939754/what-does-shadows-it-in-the-matlab-path-mean-how-to-do-it-in-a-file). Familiar-Bash-style functionatilities would be so cool.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, I think you can get that behavior with anonymous functions:

```
b = @() ls('C:\');  %I'm on windows
b()
```

The expression `b()` now returns the contents of my C drive.

Comment: Anonymous functions rock! A bit like Python's list comprehension -- and someone said that you cannot do functions without a file in matlab so wrong XD Thank you for sharing +1, so powerful tool!

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I get files with anonymous function? `a=ls('.');b=@() if isequal(a.isdir,0) a.name end` (I know I am reinventing the wheel but good learning...). It would be so cool if something like this worked, `a.isdir*a.name` -- there must be some very elegant way...

Comment: This needs to be another question or it will get lost.

Answer (score 2):

The Matlab equivalent of bash backticks is calling the `system()` function and using the second output argument. It will run an external command and capture the output.

```
[status,b] = system('ls /');
```

If it's a string of Matlab code you want to run and capture the console output of, use `evalc`.

But to just get a listing of files, you want the Matlab `dir` function. Lots easier than parsing that output string, and you get more info. See [Matlab dir documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) or `doc dir` for more details.

```
children = dir('/');
childNames = { children.name };
childIsDir = [ children.isdir ];
```

Comment: A problem with `children.name`, it contains also directories -- a flag to get only files like `"find . -type d"`?

Comment: There's also an `isdir` field in the `dir` output; you can use that to filter out the directories.