# How to make property definition using own class in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, typing

In Matlab I have the package "+mypackage". All the following definitions are under this folder/package. 
MyClass.m

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        prop1 MyProperty
    end
    
    methods (Static)
        function obj = with_five()
            obj = mypackage.MyClass(5);
        end
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = MyClass(num)
            obj.prop1 = mypackage.MyProperty(num);
        end
    end
end
```

MyProperty.m

```
classdef MyProperty    
    properties
        num double
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = MyProperty(val)
            obj.num = val;
        end
    end
end
```

So in MyClass.m I define the `prop1` property to be an object of class `MyProperty`. 
Now I would like to create objects with this script.

```
import mypackage.MyClass

class_test1 = MyClass(5);
class_test2 = MyClass.with_five();
```

When I run it I get following errors:

```
Error using Testpackage (line 3)
Error defining property 'prop1' of class 'mypackage.MyClass':
Class named 'MyProperty' is undefined or does not support property validation.
```

When I remove the property definition from MyClass.m it works.
Is there a way to define properties to be an object of an own class in Matlab?

Comment: You just need to define `prop1` as class `mypackage.MyProperty` right? Using `import` is pretty nasty because you're led to believe that everything is in the public namespace when it isn't within different scopes, if you're using a package then it's better to fully-qualify the names

Comment: Oh that was easy. Thank you! I thought I tried that already. Defining ```prop1``` with ```mypackage.MyProperty``` works! 
Do you mean the import in my script is not a good idea?

Comment: Well it's not a good idea for exactly the issue you've encountered. Namespaces are good because they avoid [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939754/what-does-shadows-it-in-the-matlab-path-mean-how-to-do-it-in-a-file), and allow you to be explicit in which function you're calling. By using `import` you are dumping everything into the main namespace from that package, but only within the scope of your script/function - which can be confusing when working across several scopes/files. You also obviously lose the advantages which namespacing offers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Wolfie your Help!
I changed the definition for `prop1` to `mypackage.MyProperty`. 
My Class definition looks now like this:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        prop1 mypackage.MyProperty
    end
    
    methods (Static)
        function obj = with_five()
            obj = mypackage.MyClass(5);
        end
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = MyClass(num)
            obj.prop1 = mypackage.MyProperty(num);
        end
    end
end
```

Its necessary to point to `MyProperty` inside my package `mypackage`. 
Otherwise Matlab is not able to find it. 
I found it in the Matlab help:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html?s_tid=srchtitle#brfynt_-3